# find a phrase/string and read the lines which corresponds to the phrase/string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is part of a file:-

```
### zones_list.txt file ########
------------------------
VSAN:1     FCID:0x6f01e0
------------------------
port-wwn (vendor)           :20:32:00:02:ac:02:74:24             
node-wwn                    :2f:f7:00:02:ac:02:74:24
class                       :3
node-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
ipa                         :ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
fc4-types:fc4_features      :scsi-fcp:target 
symbolic-port-name          :4UW0002645 - 0:3:2 - LPE32004-32G
symbolic-node-name          :HPE_3PAR A650 - 4UW0002645 - fw:4300
port-type                   :N 
port-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
fabric-port-wwn             :20:03:00:de:fb:ce:e9:40
hard-addr                   :0x000000
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :20:32:00:02:ac:02:74:24             
connected interface         :fc1/3
switch name (IP address)    :c3-sn6610c-02 (15.112.42.197)
------------------------
VSAN:1     FCID:0x6f0200
------------------------
port-wwn (vendor)           :20:33:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5             
node-wwn                    :2f:f7:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5
class                       :3
node-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
ipa                         :ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
fc4-types:fc4_features      :scsi-fcp:target 
symbolic-port-name          :4UW0002955 - 0:3:3 - LPE32004-32G
symbolic-node-name          :HPE_3PAR C630 - 4UW0002955 - fw:4210
port-type                   :N 
port-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
fabric-port-wwn             :20:0f:00:de:fb:ce:e9:40
hard-addr                   :0x000000
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :20:33:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5             
connected interface         :fc1/15
switch name (IP address)    :c3-sn6610c-02 (15.112.42.197)
------------------------
VSAN:1     FCID:0x8d0000
------------------------
port-wwn (vendor)           :10:00:00:10:9b:8c:26:64 (Emulex)    
node-wwn                    :20:00:00:10:9b:8c:26:64
class                       :3
node-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
ipa                         :ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
fc4-types:fc4_features      :
symbolic-port-name          :
symbolic-node-name          :
port-type                   :N 
port-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
fabric-port-wwn             :20:07:00:3a:9c:53:9e:b0
hard-addr                   :0x000000
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00             
connected interface         :fc1/7
switch name (IP address)    :c3-cs9148-44 (15.112.48.20)
------------------------
```

The file has 100s of entries in the above fashion. I want to find "port-wwn (vendor)           :20:32:00:02:ac:02:74:24" and read out the "connected interface" and "switch name"..
So in my code i ask the user to enter the wwn number "xx:xx:...:xx" and I search for that entry and find the Index of line and add + 13 and + 14 to the Index and print the 13th and 14th line from that Index.

The below code works which gives me the line Index corresponding to the wwn "xx:xx:...:xx"

```
with open("zones_list.txt", 'r') as f:
    #lines = f.readlines()
    for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
        if wwn in line:
            print("index is : " + str(i))
            #j = i + 13
            #k = i + 14
            #print(lines[j])
            #print(lines[k])
            break
f.close()
```

But when i want to print the lines 13th and 14th after the Index corresponding to the phase/string i desire, it is not happening any help?

```
with open("zones_list.txt", 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
    for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
        if wwn in line:
            print("index is : " + str(i))
            j = i + 13
            k = i + 14            
            print(lines[j])
            print(lines[k])
            break
f.close()
```

But the code is not working..
Any other way to write the code..?
Thank you!

Comment: Your code `for (i, line) in enumerate(f)`cannot work: f is a file descriptor. The `for` surely should work on an enumeration of the `lines` list: `for (i, line) in enumerate(lines)`. Right?

Comment: @Philippe Thanks Philippe, but i want these lines to be printed:-

port-wwn (vendor)           :20:33:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5
connected interface         :fc1/15
switch name (IP address)    :c3-sn6610c-02 (15.112.42.197)

Comment: Also you don't have to explictly close a file opened in a `with` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
wwn = input()

with open("zones_list.txt", 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   for (i, line) in enumerate(lines):
        if wwn in line:
            print("index is : " + str(i))
            j = i + 13
            k = i + 14
            print(lines[j])
            print(lines[k])
            break
```

Input:

```
20:32:00:02:ac:02:74:24
```

Output:

```
index is : 3

connected interface         :fc1/3

switch name (IP address)    :c3-sn6610c-02 (15.112.42.197)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you keep the `for` loop inside the `with` block?

Comment: @Philippe logic in OP's code involves iterating though each item in enumerate object. I tried to keep the original essence of OP's code as much as possible.

Comment: I want to find the line number/index for the key word "wwn" - so i thought that was the way..

Comment: @RishabhKumar It's just that by keeping the loop inside the `with` block, in effect, you keep the file open as long as the `for` loop is executing. While if you unindent the `for` loop, the file will be closed as soon as the `with` context block is exited. Doing this does not change the essence of what OP's code is trying to achieve in this particular case, especially since `readlines` is used. For long files and/or more involved processing within the `for` loop, keeping the file open during the loop processing may not be ideal.